# Programmatically get Windows Services and write to SQL

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to query services on a remote server and insert them into SQL.  I know I am missing something that will actually write this back but I cannot figure out what it is.  Everything works until I try to write the data to SQL.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"].ToString();
    string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"].ToString();
    string domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"].ToString();
    var logonType = SimpleImpersonation.LogonType.NewCredentials;

    using (SimpleImpersonation.Impersonation.LogonUser(domain, username, password, logonType))
    {
        var connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT ServerName, ServerIP FROM Server", conn))
            {
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string serverIP = reader["ServerIP"].ToString();
                    string serverName = reader["ServerName"].ToString();

                    ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices(serverIP);

                    foreach (ServiceController service in services)
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_InsertServices", conn))
                        {
                            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            SqlParameter ID = new SqlParameter();
                            ID.ParameterName = "@ID";
                            ID.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Display", service.DisplayName);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Service", service.ServiceName);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", service.Status);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Server", serverName);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Stored Proc

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_InsertServices]
@ID         int,
@Display    nvarchar(50),
@Service    nvarchar(50),
@Status     nvarchar(50),
@Server     nvarchar(50)

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT INTO Services
(ID,
DisplayName,
ServiceName,
Status,
Server)

VALUES
(@ID,
@Display,
@Service,
@Status,
@Server)

SET @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

END
```

EDIT: Sorry some more info.  I have added an execute at the end after the param adds and I get this error.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

Looks like I need to close the first reader but I still use it in the second command.  Don't now where I can safely close it.

Comment: close it right after you execute the first one then re open it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never execute your SqlCommand.  After you add your parameters, try adding `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

The 2nd problem is that you are trying to reuse the same SqlConnection.  You'll need to create a new SqlConnection since you are using your existing connection to loop through the list of servers.

Comment: Sorry that is one of the things I tried.  Here is the error when I execute

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

Comment: That's the error you need to fix.  You need to create a 2nd connection object since you are using your existing connection to loop through the list of servers.

Comment: Thank you.  Adding the second SQL connection fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You've built up the Command object (cmd), now you just need to save it, like `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Answer (score 1):

First this you need to change the stored procedure declaration as

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_InsertServices]
    @Display    nvarchar(50),
    @Service    nvarchar(50),
    @Status     nvarchar(50),
    @Server     nvarchar(50)

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO Services
    (DisplayName, ServiceName, Status, Server)
    VALUES
    (@Display,@Service,@Status,@Server)

    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()

END
```

And now change the calling code to

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_InsertServices", conn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Display", service.DisplayName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Service", service.ServiceName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", service.Status);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Server", serverName);

    int serviceID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    // What you want to do with the ID returned?


}
```

The ID parameter is not needed if your ID field is an IDENTITY column, it is automatically calculated by the database and you could return it using a simple select. If your stored procedure ends with a SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() the result can be retrieved on the C# code using a simple ExecuteScalar without the need of an output parameter.

Finally, if you try to ExecuteXXX an SqlCommand using the same connection in use by a SqlDataReader you get an exception because the connection is busy serving the SqlDataReader and cannot execute the command.

The simple solution is to add this to your connection string

```
  ....;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;....
```

[See MSDN for MultipleActiveResultSets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfa084cz(v=vs.110).aspx)